# Applying Transform to a widget without redrawing the widget tree

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Lets say I have this Stack:

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Column( // ==> I want to apply tranform (more specifically translate) on this
      children: [
        // a whole bunch of widgets
      ],
    ),
    Column( // ==> and this
      children: [
        // a whole bunch of widgets
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

There's two columns in the stack and each column has a huge tree of children inside of it. 
What I want to do is move the columns on the screen on specific states.

One way to achieve this is to wrap each column in an `AnimatedBuilder`, but that would mean on each frame the whole widget tree would need to be recreated which is not ideal.

In native Android, there's this method that does what I need: 
`someView.animate().translateX(100).withLayer();`

Is there an equivalent to this in flutter, or any other way to achieve this?

Comment: `AnimatedBuilder` has `child` property

Comment: @pskink I don't understand. Could you elaborate?

Comment: check the official documentation for `AnimatedBuilder.child` property (and for `AnimatedBuilder` class too)

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks. I don't know how I missed that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink, this is how it's done:

```dart
Stack(
    children: [
      AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _animation,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(_animation.value, 0),
            child: child,
          );
        },
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // a whole bunch of widgets
          ],
        ),
      ),
      ...
    ],
  );
```

The widget that needs to change to make the transform happen is `Transform.translate`, so I put that in the `builder` class, and the rest of the tree that shouldn't be affected by it, I put in the `AnimatedBuilder`'s `child` property. 
Then the child is passed back to the `builder` method, where I can just give it to child property of what's inside the builder method, and it wouldn't be rebuilt.